# What is a JSON VM747:1 error that happens during JSON parsing?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm goofing around with the [Star Wars API](https://swapi.co/) but don't get why I can't parse the data I get back:

```
<script>
$.ajax({
   url: "http://swapi.co/api/people/1/"
}).done(function( data ) {
console.log(JSON.stringify({'foo': 'bar'})) //returns {"foo":"bar"}
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'foo': 'bar'}))) //returns Object {foo: "bar"}
console.log(data); //returns Object {name: "Luke Skywalker", height: "172", mass: "77", hair_color: "blond", skin_color: "fair"…}
console.log(JSON.parse(data)) // throws error VM747:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
});
</script>
```

Comment: I find it funny that you basically already solved your problem. Notice that the console shows `Object {foo: "bar"}` for `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({'foo': 'bar'}))`. And `console.log(data)` shows you something similar. Hence `data` is already similar to what `JSON.parse` would return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` is already an object as you can see by the fact that the console logs `Object { ... }`, *not* something like `{ ... }`.

Straight from the chrome console:

[image]

Notice the different output for an *object* and for a *string*.

So: **You don't have to parse anything, just access `data` directly.**

---

> don't get why I can't parse the data

Passing an object to `JSON.parse` will convert the object to a string. So you end up doing

```
JSON.parse('[object Object]')
```

which throws an error because `[object Object]` is not valid JSON.